# Unit testing a constructor method

Tags: java, junit4

I'm having trouble getting my head round how to unit test a constructor method.

I need to check an error is being thrown. The constructor is:

```java
@Autowired
public BankDetailsValidator() {
  try {
    logDebugMessage("BankDetailsValidator() constructor");
    loadModulusWeightTable();
    loadSortCodeSubstitutionTable();
  } catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new BankDetailsValidationRuntimeException("An error occured loading the modulus weight table or sort code substitution table", e);
  }
}
```

To test this, I need to have the `loadModulusWeightTable` or `loadSortCodeSubstitutionTable` throw and `IOException`.

```java
private void loadModulusWeightTable() throws IOException {
  modulusWeightTable.clear();
  logDebugMessage("Attempting to load modulus weight table " + MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE);

  final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(MODULUS_WEIGHT_TABLE);
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  try {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      final String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
      modulusWeightTable.add(new ModulusWeightTableEntry(fields));
    }
    logDebugMessage("Modulus weight table loaded");
  }
  finally {
    br.close();
  }
}
```

I was trying to use `Spy` to have the buffered file reader return a `IOException` but couldn't get it working due to it being in the constructor.

```java
public class BankDetailsValidatorTest {

  @Spy
  private BufferedReader mockBufferReader;

  @InjectMocks
  private CDLBankDetailsValidator testSubject;

  @Test(expected = IOException.class)
  public void testIOErrorLogging() throws Exception{

    when(mockBufferReader.readLine()).thenThrow(new IOException());
    testSubject = new CDLBankDetailsValidator();
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your modulusWeightTable initialized? Is it initialized within your BankDetailsValidator?

Comment: It's not a good idea to put this code into the constructor, especially in a DI environment (Spring?). I'd suggest a `@PostConstruct` method which will be called after all beans around it have been initialized and which can be unit tested separately.

Comment: Why not to create a file with some mock data? It's better to avoid mocking if you can use some easy creatable objects like files.

Comment: Maybe refactor the `BankDetailsValidator` so that the `ModulusWeightTable` is also injected. That way, you can mock `modulusWeightTable.clear()` to throw any exception you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that class BankDetailsValidator should be refactored. In such scenarios you should extract code responsible for reading data to separate class and inject it to BankDetailsValidator as constructor parameter. After that you could test that reader separately and of course test BankDetailsValidator with mocked reader.

Comment: Yeah, the validator does need a refactor. I'm pretty new to unit testing and its driving me a bit mad.

Comment: In fairness to you, you are right in wanting to first devise a test. When there is "legacy" (untested) code it's usually a better practice to first write tests and then refactor. The only thing is that your test should probably be a "high-level" test based on the requirements rather than on the code, as you want to test whether "it works" rather than whether "it's implemented in a certain way".

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could refactor your code:

```
@Autowired
public BankDetailsValidator(Collection<ModulusWeightTableEntry> table) {
  try {
    logDebugMessage("BankDetailsValidator() constructor");
    this.modulusWeightTable.addAll(table);
    loadModulusWeightTable();
    loadSortCodeSubstitutionTable();
  } catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new BankDetailsValidationRuntimeException("An error occured loading the modulus weight table or sort code substitution table", e);
  }
}
```

which removes the loading from file part to maybe a `@Configuration`.

```
@Configuration
class WeightTableConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ModulusWeightTable loadFromFile(@Value("${mwt.filename}") String filename) {
      Collection<ModulusWeightTableEntry> table = new ArrayList<>();
      logDebugMessage("Attempting to load modulus weight table " + filename);

      try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          final String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
          table.add(new ModulusWeightTableEntry(fields));
        }
        logDebugMessage("Modulus weight table loaded");
      }
      return table;
    }
}
```

Now you can test your validator separately from the loading code, and create a separate test configuration providing a manually created weight table.

Or you parameterize your constructor with a `Supplier<WeightTable>` and put the loading code into the `get()` method of an implementing `@Component` class.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: The modulusWeightTable is just an arraylist initialized in the BankDetailsValidator right now.  So I don't have a a ModulusWeightTable class.

Comment: @JaneHayes I don't see how that matters? I replaced it with `Collection<ModulusWeightTableEntry>` which is what it looks like.